# C/C++ CSS Parser with CSS3 support?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, css

Is there any CSS parser for C/C++ with CSS3 support? I found a few but they all don't support CSS3 yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need CSS3 support before any libraries support it, you could try a non-validating solution such as [htmlcxx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlcxx/).